# How to pass the place/city name as an argument in Baidu maps?

Tags: search, maps

How can I pass the place name along with URL in Baidu maps so that Baidu automatically finds that place?

Example - Passing "Shanghai" into Google maps url will show the place Shanghai, China
http://maps.google.com.hk/maps?q=Shanghai

Any idea on how to get a similar functionality in Baidu??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "Baidu" and what does this have to do with the Google Maps API?

Comment: Baidu (www.baidu.com) is the main search engine in China. 
map.baidu.com is Baidu Maps.

I am developing for a client in China, an iPad solution which already has a functionality of Maps to show the location of a selected address for the iPad user. This was implemented using Google Maps which was the native Maps till iOS 5.1, but with iOS 6, Apple has replaced it with Apple Maps. Now the client doesn't want Apple Maps or Google Maps, they want Baidu Map, so I am replacing the native maps with a control, mini browser to which I can pass the URL and get the web page.

Comment: Google Maps works perfectly fine when I pass the URL as http://maps.google.com.hk/maps?q=Shanghai

I was wondering whether anyone has tried some similar things for Baidu.

I could not find a tag here for Baidu. (Baidu is not very famous outside China)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [API docs](http://developer.baidu.com/map/uri-intro.htm#idmykey32), the URL could be:

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/geocoder?address=%s&output=html
```

Replace `%s` with your query.